# Sort a Superclass list of objects from two Subclasses

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, superclass

I have a List from the type `Superclass A` and in that List there are multiple objects from two Subclasses, `Subclass B` and `Subclass C` and want to sort them alphabetically and then filter the objects from either Subclass, something like this:

```
List <A> listA= new ArrayList<A>();

Collections.sort(listA);
    for (A iterator : listA)
        if (iterator instanceof B)
            System.out.println(iterator);
```

My question is how should I structure my code. Should I implement `Comparable <A>` and

```
public int compareTo(A a) {
    return name.compareTo(a.getName());
}
```

in both `Superclass` and `Subclass`? If I'm not being clear enough, please say so.

EDIT: I was getting an error due to a method I had left in one of the Subclasses that was already inherited from the Superclass, and I thought the error had anything to do with the structure of the `Comparable<A>`, because I wasn't certain if it was correct, but I already had the code as all you guys told me, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can compare instances of `SuperclassA` regardless of whether they are `SubclassB` or `SubclassC`, then your solution with the `Comparable<SuperclassA>` in the superclass alone makes perfect sense. If the implementation requires knowledge of data specific to the subclasses, add abstract methods that supply this data to `SuperclassA`, and call them in your comparator.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is how should I structure my code. Should I implement Comparable  in both Superclass and Subclass?

No, it's enough if you implement it in your Superclass A. The method will be inherited by the subclasses.

Answer (score 2):

i suggest you implement a [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

```
public NameAndClassComparator implements Comparator<A> {
    public int compare(A left, a right) {
        if(left == null && right == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        if(left == null) {
            return -1;
        }
        if(right == null) {
            return 1;
        }

        int retVal = left.getname().compareTo(right.getName());

        if(retVal == 0) {
            retVal = left.getClass().getName().compareTo(right.getClass().getName());
        }

        return retVal;
    }
}
```

And then use this comparator to compare your objects:

```
Collections.sort(listA, new NameAndClassComparator());
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement Comparable only on the super class. Once implemented the subclasses will use the same method in your super class to compare instances.

If you want to compare the two subclasses differently, then you need to override the compareTo() method in your subclasses.

Even in that case, you still need to implement the Comparable on superclass.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement *Comparable* in the *Super Class A* as

```
Class A implements Comparable<A>{
    .....
    .....

    public int compareTo(Object obj){
       if( null != obj && (obj instanceOf A || obj instanceOf B || obj instanceOf C)){
         //Compare your properties here and return -1, 0 or 1 depending on the result of comparision.
        }else{
           throw new IlligalArgumentException();
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement Comparable only on the super class.Because once you will implement sub class then you can also compare instances using that method in super class.
So my advice is to implement comparable on super class.